# Can you write the japanese name Hideyoshi as 秀代志

Tags: names, spelling, kanji-choice

I know the name has common spellings like 秀吉 or 英義 but when I type ひでよし on my laptop I once got 秀代志 as an option as well. Would it work? And why/why not?

Comment: If you google 秀代志 you get results linking to facebook pages among others...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, this [reference](https://fortune-uranai.info/mei/%E7%A7%80%E4%BB%A3%E5%BF%97.html) for example.

Comment: The page you linked is a machine-generated list of names made by a fortune teller. 秀代志 works perfectly as a name, but it should be relatively rare and I doubt there are real people for all the combinations in the link.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it would work.**

As long as there is *even the most tenuous logic* to how the characters are pronounced a Japanese-style name can be made.

**Why 秀代志 works:**

- 秀 - **ひで** ⇒ from the word 秀{ひい}でる
- 代 - **よ** ⇒ is the kun-yomi for this character
- 志 - **シ** ⇒ is the on-yomi for this character